# How to convert a sample vb script code to java code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, qtp

I want to convert the below VB Script code to Java in which it should check `var2` should be present in `var1`

```
var1=test123
var2=Test 
If Instring (Ucase(var1),Ucase(var2)) <> 0 Then 
print "pass"
End IF
```

Comment: Nice that you want to convert your script to java code!

Comment: You should be able to work thorough five lines of code on your own.  What is your question?

Comment: You want to do it or you want us to do it? Please show us what you have for the Java code so far. We are not a code translation service. This is a Q&A site where the expectation is that you have already tried to implement your problem and have run out of ideas on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should qualify for a solution

```
String var1 = "test123";
String var2 = "Test";
if(var1.toUpperCase().contains(var2.toUpperCase())){
    System.out.println("pass");
}
```